# Unknown column in 'where clause' with stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I am using a stored procedure with a prepared statment to find rows from a string of email addresses.

It looks like this:

DELIMITER $$

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `get_users_by_email`(IN emailString VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email IN  (',emailString,')');
    PREPARE qry FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE qry;
END
```

I then call the procedure using:

`CALL get_users_by_email('me@email.com,you@email.com, etc..');`

But, I receive this error:

`Unknown column in 'me@email.com' in 'where clause'`

The query works if I use it to find numeric values such as:

`CALL get_users_by_email('123,456');`

Any ideas why it would be erroring on alphanumeric values? The query works fine when it is pulled out of the prepared statement and procedure.

Comment: If the email string is supplied by a human, this is a massive sql injection vulnerability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need string delimiters around your email address:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email IN  (''',emailString,''')');
```

Comment: Thank you. It has stopped the error, but It only returns results if I provide a single email address, rather than a string. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're passing a string, then you need to close the delimited before, and reopen after, each comma in your list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a string, you need to pass it with quotes:

```
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_email IN  (''',emailString,''')');
```

I used extra quotes to escape.  The numbers work since numbers are not interpreted as object names if they aren't delimited.